# Difference between Decision Trees & Behavior Trees for Game AI

Tags: architecture, ai, behavior-tree

What are some differences between Decision Trees and Behavior Trees for AI Game Development?  For what applications would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The two are pretty different. The real indicator is in the names. Decision trees are just for making decisions. Behavior trees are for controlling behavior. Allow me to explain. A major difference in the two is the way they are traversed, likewise the way they're laid out and the node 'types' are different.

**Decision trees** are evaluated from root to leaf, every time. For a decision tree to work properly, the child nodes of each parent must represent all possible decisions for that node. If a node can be answered "Yes, No, Maybe", there must be three children, Yes node, No node and Maybe node. This means there's always some lower node to traverse, until reaching an end node. The traversal is always down. Graphical form:

[image]

Pretty simple. We start at the root, and based on some evaluation, choose 1, 2 or 3. We choose 3. Then we do some other evaluation and choose B or B... Well I reused the graphic from below, sorry. Pretend the B on the left is magic B.

**Behavior trees** have a different evaluation. The first time they are evaluated (or they're reset) they start from the root (parent nodes act like selectors) and each child is evaluated from left to right. The child nodes are ordered based on their **priority**. If all of a child node's conditions are met, its behavior is started. When a node starts a behavior, that node is set to 'running', and it returns the behavior. The next time the tree is evaluated, it again checks the highest priority nodes, then when it comes to a 'running' node, it knows to pick up where it left off. The node can have a sequence of actions and conditions before reaching an end state. If any condition fails, the traversal returns to the parent. The parent selector then moves on to the next priority child. I'll attempt a graphical form here:

[image]

The traversal starts at the root, goes to child 1, checks the child condition (something like "any enemies near by?"). The condition fails, and the traversal moves back up the tree to move on to node two. Node 2 has an action that's performed (maybe something like finding a path). Then a behavior (something like following the path). The following path is set to running and the tree returns its state as running. The nodes that failed or completed are returned to 'Ready'. Then the next time we check, we start again with the highest priority node. It fails again, so we proceed to node two. There we find we have a behavior running. We also find the behavior has completed, so we mark it completed and return that. The tree is then reset and ready to go again.

As you can see the behavior trees are more complex. Behavior trees are more powerful and allow for more complex behavior. Decision trees are easy to understand and simple to implement. So, you'd use behavior trees when you want more complex behavior, or more control over the behavior. Decision trees can be used as part of a behavior tree, or used alone for simple AI.

Some good understanding of how behavior trees are parsed can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131209105717/http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/02/24/introduction-to-behavior-trees/).

Comment: Great explanation and illustrations.  So when you say "If all of a child node's conditions are met..." do Selectors and Sequences contain conditions or only leaf nodes, ie the Actions?

Comment: The child nodes are behaviors, actions, conditions or selectors with more children. They're evaluated from left to right.

Comment: Great post, though I think I still have an outstanding question (will post separately). What did you use to create the animated GIFs?

Comment: 0-2-A shouldn't be play again if 0-2-B is running ???      https://github.com/pirobot/pi_trees/issues/1

Comment: @nopnop77 Not if the 0-2 conditional still evaluates to 0-2-B. You can see that 0-2 is reevaluated, but once again doesn't result in A being selected.

Comment: @MichaelHouse Same question as above.
Why doesn't the tree reavaluate 0-2-B directly instead of traversing from left, as in why does it revaluate 0-1-C again, if 0-2-B is still running?

My concern is in a scenario where 0-2-B could be running and 0-1-C doesn't fail, causing the selector to skip 0-2-B, how do you properly handle the running task then?

Comment: @Seivan Likely the task is halted. You get to define the behavior. Since 0-1-C is a higher priority, if it's true, you want to process it before the lower priority items, like 0-2-B. i.e, if you're gathering materials and you're attacked, you want to respond to that attack instead of continuing to gather materials.

Comment: @MichaelHouse Do you make a distinction between Selector and Sequences when they revaluate running children?

I noticed that `1` and `2` are `Sequences` while `A` (Root?) behaves like a `Selector`, and when it evaluates a second time, it goes directly from `2-B` and doesn't check `2-A` at all.

Now, I assume that's because `2-B` is running and jumps directly there, but the root also checks `A`. 

Is this a mistake or by design? As in shouldn't it go `2-A` first before checking on `2-B` the second time around?

Comment: @Seivan `2` is behaving as a selector. In this case, `A` ran once, completed and then was not selected the next time. It's up to the developer if a running `B` is more important than `A`. In the animation above, `A` was simply not selected, and not because `B` happened to be running. Just like `0`-`1`-`B` is not visited when `1` selects `A` instead.

Comment: @MichaelHouse I am sorry, but are you absolutely sure that in your Example `2` is a Selector?

A Selector will try until it hits `Success` in your Example `2` behaves  as as a Sequence as it requires previous node to succeed to continue to the next one. Maybe you got it confused, or did I ?

Comment: @Seivan Could be either :) Check out the updated link at the bottom of my answer for a second opinion.